# Redmine: remove archived projects

Tags: redmine, redmine-api, python-redmine

I would like to remove all archived projects on my redmine installation. Doing so from my browser works, but I have 400 of them...

I had the idea to script it, but the [redmine REST api](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_python) doesn't seem to expose the deletion of archived projects... And there is no "Remove all" feature from the administration panel.

Did any of you already had to deal with those kind of things?

Comment: If You are familiar with Rails You may do it from rails console.

Answer (score 0):

try python-redmine library:

```
from redmine import Redmine

redmine = Redmine('http:///', username='', password='')
projects = redmine.project.all()
for project in projects:
    print project.status, project.id
for project in projects:
    if project.status == 5:
        redmine.project.delete(project.id)
```

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-redmine/latest/python-redmine.pdf